# Very slow SMB read speeds from share to M1 MBP. Write speeds are normal. VNC speeds normal both directions. Workaround?

Tags: smb, file-sharing, big-sur, apple-silicon

I own a handful of MacBook Pros, including a new 13" M1 running Big Sur 11.0.1 (16Gb, 2TB). Connecting M1 to 16" MBP over ethernet using SMB works, but I only get full speed (Cat 5e) when writing to the network. Reading from the 16" MBP is 1 MB/s to a max of ~5MB/s. Swapping the M1 MacBook Pro with a 2019 Intel MacBook Pro, and SMB speeds are back to normal in both directions.

Apple just told me that this is a known issue, but I noticed that if I drag and drop files between the machines using Screen Sharing, the transfer executes at full speed in both directions.

If there is no fix other than waiting for the next iteration of Big Sur, can I somehow use the VNC protocol to mount a shared drive as I would using SMB?

If not, is any other workaround possible?

Comment: just for more data : I am having similar issues when connected to an external HDD over SMB connection (through a portable wifi router/hotspot/range-extender) when copying files from SMB drive to HDD (haven't tried the other way).